# Google Classroom Add IAM Policy Binding

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-classroom

I am working on Google Classroom Pub/Sub Notification. I have task which is create the pub/sub topic and subscription by using the Rest API. I have created the pub/sub topic successfully but when i am setting the IAM Policy/Permissions for created topic then i am getting the error message.

**API URL:-** https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-abc/topics/xyz-topic-101:setIamPolicy
**API Method:-** POST
**API Request Body:-**

```
{
    "policy": {
        "bindings": [
            {
                "role": "roles/owner",
                "members": [
                    "abc@domain.com",
                    "classroom-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
            },
            {
                "role": "roles/pubsub.admin",
                "members": [
                    "abc@domain.com",
                    "classroom-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
            },
            {
                "role": "roles/pubsub.editor",
                "members": [
                    "abc@domain.com",
                    "classroom-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
            },
            {
                "role": "roles/pubsub.publisher",
                "members": [
                    "abc@domain.com",
                    "classroom-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
            },
            {
                "role": "roles/pubsub.subscriber",
                "members": [
                    "abc@domain.com",
                    "classroom-notifications@system.gserviceaccount.com"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "version": 1
    }
}
```

**API Response:-**
{
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "The member abc@domain.com is of an unknown type. Please set a valid type prefix for the member.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}

I have follow the below Google Doc
**Link:-** https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/Policy#Binding
I am not getting that why this message is coming. Please share your suggestions & feedback's.

Comment: Referring to the official doc: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/error-codes we can say that this error happens when "The request is invalid; a required argument may be missing, exceeds limits, or has an invalid value." I would recommend to check the Pub/Sub quotas and limits: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas LEt me know if you exceed any of them.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this will help, but I found that you need to [set the member type](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/functions/add-iam-policy-binding#REQUIRED-FLAGS) for this to work.

From doc:

> Should be of the form user|group|serviceAccount:email or domain:domain.

So try adding the prefix, along the lines of: `serviceAccount:abc@domain.com`, or whatever your member type is.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot comment at this moment but Voy's answer fix this issue. you must add the type of the member. Below section taken from google cloud documentation :

*Examples: user:test-user@gmail.com, group:admins@example.com, serviceAccount:test123@example.domain.com, or domain:example.domain.com.
Can also be one of the following special values:
allUsers - Special identifier that represents anyone who is on the internet, with or without a Google account.
allAuthenticatedUsers - Special identifier that represents anyone who is authenticated with a Google account or a service account.*

Comment: what I meant is that because of my reputation I cant upvote... Thats why I added a comment

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've attempted to use the service account name, but it expected to see a **type of an account** in a **prefix**.

What I used :

```
xyz@gcp-airflow-k8s.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

What is expected :

```
serviceaccount:xyz@gcp-airflow-k8s.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```